# Absolute String matching in python

Tags: python, string

I've list of people names in list,names are unique are but sometimes first name may appear after last name and vice versa.eg.
`list[0]="Albert Einstein" and list[5]="Einstein Albert"`
but finally I want one unique entry for each name
I tried edit dist but value returned may vary over wide range  so not useful 
please suggest good string matching module in python

Comment: So what if there are two different people, one called "Arnold Dieter" and one called "Dieter Arnold". Would your program just figure these are the same guys? If yes, what purpose would that serve? If no, I don't see how this is actually possible. Also, what have you tried so far? Show us some code so we can figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: I want to allocate number of machines per user if there are "duplicate entries" then it'll be problematic

Comment: So what about those two guys, "Arnold Dieter" and "Dieter Arnold". Do you want to remove one of those although they are two differen people? Wouldn't that be unfair??

Comment: No but in my situation I know Arnold Dieter and Dieter Arnold are not different.what you are saying is correct but i assure that these are same persons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> x = ["Albert Einstein", "test 1 s 2", "Einstein Albert", "foo bar baz", "baz foo bar"]
>>> list(set(' '.join(sorted(s.split())) for s in x))
['bar baz foo', '1 2 s test', 'Albert Einstein']
```

Comment: Sorry, I fail to see how this differs from my solution (expect that's it uses a list comprehension instead of a genexpr for no reason...).

Comment: It doesn't differ significantly, and I agree that its better with generators.  But if you're just trying to rub it in that F.J. came up with the same solution I did while I was testing mine in IDLE, I refuse to be intimidated.  :-)

Comment: Let me remove those unnecessary parens. Sorry for my harsh comment, didn't mean to intimidate :)

Comment: upto some cases it'll work but still it may fail anyways thanks for giving me direction

Answer (score 2):

Another way which also doesn't guarantee that the order of the name parts will be preserved if there is no duplicate:

```
>>> name_list = ["Albert Einstein", "Einstein Albert", "Abe Lincoln", "Lincoln Abe"]
>>> list(set(' '.join(sorted(n.split())) for n in name_list))
['Abe Lincoln', 'Albert Einstein']
```

#### Algorithm

1. For each name `n`, take it apart (`n.split()`), sort the parts (`sorted(n.split())`) and rejoin them (`' '.join(sorted(n.split()))`). Duplicates will now have the same representation
2. Make a `set` out of the resulting generator to remove duplicates
3. Transform the temporary `set` back into a list (although this might not be strictly necessary).